# Odoo POS receipt error

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I'm using Odoo v11 in windows localhost and I'm still beginner.

Recently, i tried to edit posticket and suddenly, the point of sale module stops loading it keep blank page.

I have cleared cache for browser and restart odoo service, it worked.

But, the receipt not showing and error message appears as showing below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vat_label' of null
http://localhost:8069/point_of_sale/static/src/js/models.js:2121
Traceback:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'vat_label' of null
at child.export_for_printing 
(http://localhost:8069/point_of_sale/static/src/js/models.js:2121:44)
at Class.get_receipt_render_env 
(http://localhost:8069/point_of_sale/static/src/js/screens.js:1538:28)
at Class.render_receipt 
(http://localhost:8069/point_of_sale/static/src/js/screens.js:1616:77)
at Class.show 
(http://localhost:8069/point_of_sale/static/src/js/screens.js:1505:14)
at Class.prototype.(anonymous function) [as show] 
(http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:90:38)
at Class.show_screen 
(http://localhost:8069/point_of_sale/static/src/js/gui.js:116:33)
at Class.finalize_validation 
(http://localhost:8069/point_of_sale/static/src/js/screens.js:2071:22)
at Class.validate_order [as _super] 
(http://localhost:8069/point_of_sale/static/src/js/screens.js:2080:18)
at Class.validate_order 
(http://localhost:8069/pos_mercury/static/src/js/pos_mercury.js:687:14)
at Class.validate_order 
(http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:123:38)
```

Edit :

I have removed all `HTML` codes i inserted to posticket, now it only working when i activate developer mode with assets. When deactivate and try generate pos sale receipt it gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vat_label' of null
http://localhost:4883/web/content/2266-abace1e/point_of_sale.assets.js:197
Traceback:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'vat_label' of null
at child.export_for_printing (http://localhost:4883/web/content/2266-
abace1e/point_of_sale.assets.js:197:863)
at Class.get_receipt_render_env (http://localhost:4883/web/content/2266-
abace1e/point_of_sale.assets.js:379:1110)
at Class.render_receipt (http://localhost:4883/web/content/2266-
abace1e/point_of_sale.assets.js:379:2226)
at Class.show (http://localhost:4883/web/content/2266-
abace1e/point_of_sale.assets.js:379:409)
at Class.prototype.(anonymous function) [as show] 
(http://localhost:4883/web/content/2189-
2963aaa/web.assets_common.js:3816:488)
at Class.show_screen (http://localhost:4883/web/content/2266-
abace1e/point_of_sale.assets.js:314:48)
at Class.finalize_validation (http://localhost:4883/web/content/2266-
abace1e/point_of_sale.assets.js:400:1111)
at Class.validate_order [as _super] (http://localhost:4883/web/content/2266-
abace1e/point_of_sale.assets.js:400:1226)
at Class.validate_order (http://localhost:4883/web/content/2266-
abace1e/point_of_sale.assets.js:448:6)
at Class.validate_order (http://localhost:4883/web/content/2189-
2963aaa/web.assets_common.js:3819:371)
```

I really appreciate your help and support.

Regards,

Comment: Check the _vat_label_ object. It is trying to read property or attribute of that object but the object contains null value. Check the code whether the value has been assigned for that object or not before using it.

Comment: @PyMaster Thank you for your reply. if follow where the error pointing its writing: `vat_label: company.country.vat_label,` , i don't know what return null value.

Comment: vat_label isn't available . Please find correct field instead of vat_label

Comment: There is no such field in res.company

Comment: vat_label  isn't a correct field . Please remove this right now ..

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `<t t-esc="widget.pos.company.name"/>` in posticket is returning that invalid values from `modles.js` at `vat_label: company.country.vat_label,`. 
Unfortunately, I have removed those two lines and everything works fine now.

I keep investigating on this and i will keep you updated.

Thanks for your support and assistance.

Regards,
Mhdbtashi

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me last night after I delete country data from my company in the settings page. But when I put my country back to my company set-up. it works again. Not sure if this can help. I'm a non-tech person.

Answer (score -1):

this error is related to the country and the field called Tax IVA name, and your company need established by default some country.